# Inverse of metric tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors

The following is a homework example, but I have the feeling that it is not stated correctly, and I would like to hear some opinions on that:

---

> Let $g_{ij}$ be a symmetric non-degenerate tensor field. Now define:
> $$ B_i \enspace := \enspace g_{ij} A^j \qquad \text{and} \qquad C^i \enspace := \enspace g^{ij} B_j $$
> Show that
> $$ C^i \enspace = \enspace A^i \tag{1}$$

---

Equation (1) shows that $g_{ij}$ is inverse to $g^{jk}$ -- existence of such an inverse is guaranteed by non-degeneracy.

The tensor field $g$ is in the following examples introduced as the metric. However, until now I always worked with **defining** $g^{jk}$ to be the inverse of $g_{ij}$. Now that I have to **show** it, fail to accomplish that. I have the feeling that it may not be possible from the information given.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the exercise is asking you to use the fact that $g^{ij}$ is the inverse of $g_{ij}$ to prove that $g^{ij}g_{jk}A^{k}=A^i$.

Answer (score 3):

> until now I always worked with **defining** $g^{jk}$ to be the inverse of $g_{ij}$. Now that I have to **show** it

That's not how I read the question. I read it as asking you to use $C^i=g^{ij}g_{jk}A^k=\delta^i_kA^k=A^i$, where $g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$ is the definition of $g^{ij}$ used in the definition of $C^i$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You do think that I can a-priori assume the identity $g^{ij} \cdot g_{jk} = \delta^i_k$ to hold?

Comment: @Octavius well, how would you define $g^{ij}$ otherwise?

Comment: @Didier Well, thats the point, isn't it? As far as I understand the problem statement, one does not have an explicit definition of $g^{ij}$. Only when proving that $C^i = A^i$ one finds $g^{ij}$ to be the inverse of $g_{ij}$. Or do I terribly misread the problem statement? I mean, if I can assume $g^{ij}$ to be the inverse, then wheres the difficulty in that problem?

Comment: @Octavius Well, as $C^i$ is defined thanks to $g^{ij}$, you should define it before... And perhaps you are overthinking. Sometimes, homeworks are easy, and are just here so that you clearly understand the definitions.

Comment: You are probably right. Thanks for your answers.